# EmberJS, How access in a child template to the model in the parent controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember.js-2

I have this `router`:

```
// app/router.js
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('battle', function(){
    this.route('combats');
  })
});
```

In the combats route I can access to the battle model easily using:

```
// app/routes/battle/combat.js
this.modelFor('battle');
```

But if I want to access to this model also in the combats template things start to be complicate:

```
// app/templates/battle/combats.hbs
<h1>Combats for Battle {{<how to access to the battle>.title}}</h1>

{{#each model as |combat|}}
  {{combat.date}}
{{/each}}
```

I have solved this sending properties to the combats Controller from the combats Route:

```
// app/routes/battle/combat.js
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  controller.set('content', model);
  controller.set('battle', this.modelFor('battle'));
}
```

But I don't know if it is the correct way, it looks too much *indirect* under my perspective, like that you have to make a long workaround to make this property available in the template.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how generic you want your code to be. For your special usecase it might be appropriate to use the Ember.RSVP.hash in your model hook in `combats.js` like this:

```
model(){
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        combats: //here your combat.js model code,
        battle: this.modelFor('battle');
    })
}
```

Then you can remove your setupController function and rewrite your template to:

```
<h1>Combats for Battle {{model.battle.title}}</h1>

{{#each model.combats as |combat|}}
  {{combat.date}}
{{/each}}
```